# Do specific Council of Ministers configurations run on rotation?

Tags: european-union, european-council

There are a number of different configurations for the Council of Ministers, each corresponding to a policy area.

Do these configurations gather ad-hoc or on rotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might depends on the configuration.

- [ECOFIN](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/ecofin/) (Economic and Financial), which is one of the oldest (configurations) generally meets once a month. (Likewise for [AGRIFISH](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/agrifish/) and [Foreign Affairs](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/fac/).)
- [COMPET](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/compet/), which is newer, meets (at least) four times a year. Likewise for the Environment ([ENV](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/env/)) and [JHA](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/jha/) (Justice and Home Affairs).
- TTE (Transport, Telecommunications and Energy) even though it's theoretically one config, in practice [it's three](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/tte/):

> The composition of the TTE Council and the number of its meetings varies according to the items on the agenda:
>
> - transport ministers usually meet four times a year
> - energy ministers meet three or four times a year
> - telecommunications ministers meet twice a year

- Another "jumbo" config is Education, Youth, Culture and Sport Council configuration ([EYCS](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/council-eu/configurations/eycs/))

> The precise composition of the Council depends on the items discussed in a particular meeting. [...] The EYCS Council meets three or four times a year; twice in its full configuration.

Etc. I'm not sure there's one that meets entirely ad-hoc. It looks like twice a year is the minimum frequency and once a month is the maximum for regular meetings of some arbitrary config.

Comment: Very interesting to see they have those different configurations. Wikipedia has a [more extensive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Council_of_the_European_Union#Configurations).